# QGIS: Filter by click?

Tags: qgis, filter

I am editing a polygon layer in QGIS 3.20. During this task I need to filter the layer by a certain attribute. This needs to be done like a 100 times on a workday. The workflow is like:

- Visually identify a polygon feature on the map
- Show all the polygons with the same attribute value

Until now I just looked up the attribute value and then changed the filter expression manually. But I wonder if there is a more straightforward method. Ideally I could change the filter expression by just clicking on a feature.

Answer (score 4):

If I interpret your question correctly, you can fire a function when the map canvas is clicked and update the layer's selected features by matching them with a clicked feature.

To activate the tool, you can copy-paste this code into a new script in the Script Editor of the Python console and run it. If you use a different tool, such as pan or select, you will need to run the script again to re-activate this tool.

The grid I used had an attribute column `random_identifier` that was a random integer between `1` and `6`

I chose selection over filtering, because polygons that do not match the filter will not be shown and will therefore be unclickable.

```py
## get your working layer
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Grid')[0]

## the name of the field that you want to select features with matching values
field_to_match = 'random_identifier' 

## the index of the field to match
idx = lyr.fields().indexFromName(field_to_match)

# get reference to the map canvas 
canvas = iface.mapCanvas() 

## define a function to fire when the mouse is clicked on the canvas
def select_matching_features(point, mouse_button): 
    ## get features in layer (it is inside the function in case edits are made)
    feats = list(lyr.getFeatures())
    
    ## make a QgsGeometry from a QgsPointXY at the click location on the canvas
    clicked_point = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(point.x(), point.y()))

    ## set the clicked id to be non-existing
    id = -1

    ## iterate through features and test for an intersection with the mouse click
    for feat in feats:
        if clicked_point.within(feat.geometry()):
            id = feat.id()
            break
    
    ## if there is an intersection
    if id != -1:
        ## initialise a list to store the matching features
        feats_to_select = []
        
        ## get the attribute value from the clicked feature
        value_to_match = feat.attributes()[idx]
        print('value to match', value_to_match)
        
        ## iterate through the features
        for f in feats:
            ## if the feature's attribute matches the clicked feature, add the feature to the selected features list
            if f.attributes()[idx] == value_to_match:
                feats_to_select.append(f)
        
        ## select all matching features in layer
        lyr.selectByIds([selected_feat.id() for selected_feat in feats_to_select])
        
    else:
        print ("No feature selected")

# instantiate a QgsMapTool that makes a QgsPoint when the map canvas is clicked
pointTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(canvas)

## connect the function above to the signal emitted by the mouse click
pointTool.canvasClicked.connect(select_matching_features)

## activate the QgsMapTool
canvas.setMapTool(pointTool)
```

##### Note

the screen capture software I used has rendered my cursor in a slightly different position than it actually was. Rest assured, the polygons I am clicking are properly selected.

[image: Image from Gyazo]

Comment: Matt, thats great, many thanks! Exactly the approach I was looking for. In fact I need to filter instead of selecting because I need the other features to disappear while editing (long story behind that...). But I guess I can adapt your example with layer.setSubsetString() and write a second small script which essentially just clears the filter so everything is showed again after editing a subset. Just one small question to your example code: how can I terminate it? I mean, just return to standard mouse pointer and "normal" QGIS behaviour when clicking?

Comment: Just saw that you already answered my question how to terminate the script: just use another tool...

Comment: Indeed! I don't have much experience with QgsMapTool so terminating by using another tool is not the most graceful way, but it works. I found this an interesting problem/request and I might make it into a little plugin that has more user-friendly behaviour, perhaps with an expression editor and an option to either select or filter.

Comment: Adding 'pointTool.canvasClicked.disconnect()' did the trick for me, or at least the function stops firing. For my specific needs I need the function to just fire once, so i added this just at the end of the function.

Comment: I think this could be a handy tool, too! Unfortunately my programming skills are too limited to write plugins...